# Microsoft Word API Permission Denied

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, api

I have been trying to create a word add-in, however trying to access either the body's HTML or text using context.document.body is giving me permission denied.

The permissions in the add-in's manifest file are set to ReadWriteDocument and I am also using office 365 just to be sure that I have the most up to date version of word so I am not sure what is wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function loadSampleData() {
        // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
        Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.         
            var body = context.document.body;             
            console.log(body);
```

Error Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I finally figured it out. To access attributes that say  we need to load the attribute first using .load(), then we can access it in the promise.

For example:

```
var documentBody = context.document.body;
documentBody.load('Ooxml');    
return context.sync().then(function () {
       console.log(documentBody.getOoxml);  
});
```